# How would you measure Response Time of Multi-threaded C# Request?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, request, hangfire

C# definitely isn't my wheelhouse and I've only ever dealt with JavaScript and JS frameworks, but I need to measure the response times of an endpoint request, from the beginning of the parent request to the end of the last child request. These are multithreaded and programmed in C#. The requests are processed by Hangfire.Io. In JS I would listen for the last callback and measure the RT from start to finish. Any ideas for frameworks, packages, or techniques that I could use to accomplish this? Thanks guys!

Comment: Please provide a sample code of what you have so far, otherwise it will be hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often used the `StopWatch` of .Net/C#. See [MSN Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

For example:

```
var stopWatch = new StopWatch();
stopWatch.Start();
try
{
    DoSomething(...);
}
finally
{
   stopWatch.Stop();
   var elapsed = stopWatch.Elapsed; // Getting the duration as TimeSpan object
   console.WriteLine($"Duration: {elapsed.ToString("c")}");
}
```

If you give us more details about what kind of C# application (Console, Owin, ASP.Net MVC, etc.) your are implementing, we may can help where to best hook the above code into.